# Conditional Parameter Substitution while using cat

Tags: bash

I'm using cat to create file from environment variable.

```
cat <<EOF > config
environment = ${ENVIRONMENT:-dev}
EOF
```

I need dev, even if it is `development` or `develop`. I cannot trim  it because, it has other possible values like `qa`, `demo`, `staging` etc.

Please Note: I cannot use if statement, in my environment. Its used in Jenkins Execute Shell, I have a parameterized build, using if will require me repeat the above cat, multiple times

Any easy way Guys..

regards,
Shan

Comment: It's as simple as `environment=${ENVIRONMENT/dev*/dev}`. When `ENVIRONMENT` contains the word `dev` followed by any number of characters after it, replace with `dev`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cat <<EOF > config
  environment = $([[ "${ENVIRONMENT}" =~ ^dev ]] && ENVIRONMENT=dev && echo $ENVIRONMENT)
EOF
```

Comment: You don't really need an RE here (which older versions don't support) `[[ $ENVIRONMENT == dev* ]]` would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

There is no [*parameter substitution*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) operation that can do what you want. I suggest to place a conditional in front of the `cat` command, like this:

```
if [[ "${ENVIRONMENT}" =~ ^dev ]] ; then
    ENVIRONMENT="dev"
fi

cat <<EOF > config
environment = ${ENVIRONMENT}
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks @hek2mgl, I have a lot of things like this. dev is an eample. But, this will do, saves me from repeating the cat.  Many thanks